# how to configure smtp settings

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtpclient

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Partial Class ContactUs
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
        Dim username = User.Identity.Name.ToString
        Response.Redirect("~/ViewCart_aspx/ViewCart.aspx?userID=" & username)
    End Sub
    Protected Sub CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidator1.ServerValidate
        If txtComments.Text.Length > 200 Then
            args.IsValid = False
        Else
            args.IsValid = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub WizardStep3_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles WizardStep3.Load
        lblName.text = txtName.Text
        lblEmail.Text = txtEmail.Text
        lblComments.Text = txtComments.Text
        lblRating.Text = txtRatings.Text
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles Wizard1.FinishButtonClick
        SendMail(txtEmail.Text, txtComments.Text)
        'MsgBox("Feedback Sent")
        Response.Redirect("homepage_aspx/homepage.aspx")

    End Sub

    Private Sub SendMail(ByVal from As String, ByVal body As String)

        Dim mMailSettings As System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup

        Dim mPort As Integer = mMailSettings.Smtp.Network.Port
        Dim mHost As String = mMailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host
        Dim mPassword As String = mMailSettings.Smtp.Network.Password
        Dim mUsername As String = mMailSettings.Smtp.Network.UserName
        'Dim mailServerName As String = "smtp.tricedeals.com"
        'Dim message As MailMessage = New MailMessage(from, "admin@tricedeals.com", "feedback", body)
        'Dim mailClient As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient

        'mailClient.Host = mailServerName
        'mailClient.Send(message)
        'message.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    End Sub
End Class
```

what is wrong with my smtp settings??i cant send emails.please help me.

Comment: what behavior did you observe ?

Comment: when i click on the finish button...nothing happens.i am using a wizard control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't send email because the send command is commented out. since you don't give more details or better explanation or exception message that's the only thing I can assume.